# Как начислить валюту за нахождение в войсе?

Tags: python, discord.py, discord

```
@client.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    with open('economy.json','r') as f:
        money = json.load(f)
    author = member.id
    if before.channel is None and after.channel is not None:
        print('1')
        t1 = time.time()
        tdict[author] = t1
    elif before.channel is not None and after.channel is None and author in tdict:
        t2 = time.time()
        print('0')
        print(t2-tdict[author])
        tdict1[author] = t2
    else:
        await (tdict1[author]-tdict[author]) > 13
        money[str(author)]['Money'] += 1
    with open('economy.json','w') as f:
        json.dump(money,f)
```

Выдает ошибку:Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "Ice.py", line 468, in on_voice_state_update
    await (tdict1[author]-tdict[author]) > 13
NameError: name 'tdict1' is not defined
```

Comment: name 'tdict1' is not defined, переменная как минимум не найдена.

Comment: Спасибо за код, себе взял) рабочий. Добавьте где то в глобальных местах переменные dict "tdict" и "tdict1" и всё.